# How to conform to a protocol's variables' set & get?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, getter-setter, swift-protocols

I'm playing around with protocols and how to conform to them.

```
protocol Human {    
    var height: Int { get set }    
}

struct Boy: Human { 
    var height: Int  { return 5 } // error!
}
```

I'm trying to learn different ways that I can implement set and get.
However the code above throws the following error:

> type 'Boy' does not conform to protocol 'Human'

However writing as below won't have any errors:

```
struct Boy: Human { 
    var height = 5 // no error
}
```

I don't understand the difference nor what exactly needs to be implemented when you can also *set* a variable. I looked into different questions and tutorials but they all just write and go without any deeper explanation.

**EDIT:**
make sure you see Imanou's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38281420/5175709). It greatly explains the different scenarios.

Comment: FWIW     `struct boy : Human { 
        let height = 5 // error!
    }` would also produce an error. The reason is mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40820913/how-can-you-conform-protocol-variables-set-get/40820968?noredirect=1#comment85239656_40820968) comment by Martin. *`var` declares a variable, and `let` a constant. As stored properties, the first is read/write and the second read-only*

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From the [Swift Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html):

> **Property Requirements**
>
> ...
> The protocol doesn’t specify whether the property should be a stored property or a computed property—it only specifies the required property name and type.
> ...
> Property requirements are always declared as variable properties, prefixed with the `var` keyword. Gettable and settable properties are indicated by writing `{ get set }` after their type declaration, and gettable properties are indicated by writing `{ get }`.

In your case

```
var height: Int  {return 5} // error!
```

is a *computed property* which can only be *get,* it is a
shortcut for

```
var height: Int {
    get {
        return 5
    }
}
```

But the `Human` protocol requires a property which is gettable and settable.
You can either conform with a stored *variable* property (as you noticed):

```
struct Boy: Human { 
    var height = 5
}
```

or with a computed property which has *both getter and setter:*

```
struct Boy: Human { 
    var height: Int {
        get {
            return 5
        }
        set(newValue) {
            // ... do whatever is appropriate ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `var height = 5` how does this make conform to both get and set?

Comment: @Honey: `var` declares a *variable* which can be both set and get.

Comment: @Honey: `{ get set }` in the protocol indicates a *gettable and settable property,* and it does not matter if that is a stored or a computed property. I have added a link to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Using your answer I was able to write an answer on my own. So you should only be using computed properties if 1) you have a good reason ie you want to compute something based on something else. Otherwise it doesn't make sense right? 2) You ALWAYS need a stored property to back it up right? 3) in the stored property implementation which you did... simply using `var` leaves the door open for the variable to be set in a very normal way. right?

Comment: @Honey: "good reason" or "anything special" is a bit vague. A stored property provides storage for a value, a computed property doesn't. A computed property might also save a value to a database, for example. A read-only computed property might need no backing store at all.

Comment: when you compute doesn't provide storage, you mean it will never have a memory location and *always* it needs to read/use the stored property and then compute to give a value?

Comment: @Honey: *If* the setter of a computed property wants to persist the information then it needs *some* backing store. That can be a stored property, the user defaults, a file, a database, a web service, etc. But the *language* does not require that. A "do-nothing" setter as above is valid Swift code (even if useless :)

Comment: "var declares a variable which can be both set and get." you mean inherent in the definition of the `var` syntax is that all variables are settable and gettable unless you specify otherwise?

Comment: @Honey: `var` declares a variable, and `let` a constant. As *stored properties,* the first is read/write and the second read-only.

Comment: The intriguing part here is "// ... do whatever is appropriate ..." in set. Simply `height = newValue` will give these warnings: `Attempting to modify 'height' within its own setter`, and `All paths through this function will call itself`.  Very confused...

Comment: @Koen: Compare my above comment: *“If the setter of a computed property wants to persist the information then it needs some backing store. ...”* – Or simply use a *computed property:*  `var height = 5`

Answer (score 18):

## Prerequisite:

Read my blog post on [Swift Protocol Compile time check](https://mfaani.com/posts/swift-protocol-compile-time-check/)

It will answer to A LOT of your questions. Then read the rest.

Go into your playground and just write the snippet below:

```
var height: Int {
    get {
        return 5
    }
}
```

or similarly:

```
var height: Int {
    return 5
}
```

Try to print `height`'s value, obviously works. So far so good

```
print(height) // prints 5
```

However if you try to **set** it to a new value then you'll get an error:

```
height = 8 // ERROR
```

> error: cannot assign to value: 'height' is a get-only property

---

## Answer:

Based on Martin's answer, I first wrote:

```
set(newValue) {
    height = newValue 
}
```

Which put a ton of load on my memory and led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025340/property-getters-and-setters/38308902#38308902) question. Please take a look. So then I was figuring out what to write, and I kind of understood that if you don't want to do anything special you **shouldn't** be using computed properties and instead you should just use normal stored properties.

So I wrote a *similar* code

```
protocol Human {

    var height: Float {get set}

}

struct Boy: Human {
    
    // inch
    var USheight : Float
    
    // cm
    var height: Float {
        get {
            return 2.54 * USheight
        }
        set(newValue) {
         USheight = newValue/2.54
            
        }
    }
}

// 5 ft person
var person = Boy(USheight: 60)
 // interestingly the initializer is 'only' based on stored properties because they
 // initialize computed properties. 


// equals to 152cm person
print(person.height) // 152.4
```

---

### Pro tip: When should you should make your properties read-only?

Normally if you make a property to be read-only ie  `{ get }` it's because those properties are **computed** and you don't want the object to have control over it.

Example you have a JSON object. It has multiple big objects like:

```
JSONData
 - userInfo (name, address, age)
 - devices (iPads, iPhones, Mac books)
 - credentials (basic iCloud, pro iCloud, celebrity)
```

by making the role a read-only you're only allowing the server to tell the code base the role of the user.

```
protocol Credentials {
    var role: String { get }
    
    init(person: Person)
}

class Person {
    var userInfo: String
    var devices: [String]
    var creds: Credentials {
        Credentials(person: self)
    }
    
    init(userInfo: userInfo, devices: [String]) {
        self.userInfo = userInfo
        self.devices = devices
    }
}
```