# In Swift do you not have to use a getter and setter when creating an object type, such as class, that conforms to a protocol requiring so?

Tags: swift, swift4

```
protocol UserType {
    var name: String { get }
    var age: Int { get set }


struct Person: UserType { 
    var name: String //<- why is this okay?
    var age: Int //<- why is this okay? dont we need a getter setter
}

let somePerson = Person(name: "Billy", age: 22)
```

Why in the above examples, we dont use get constructs or set constructs for age and a get construct for name? Is it because in the protocol when the property is said to "{ get set }" that essentially means it has to be able to be read and has to be able to be changed, which can be done through a declaration in the syntax of a stored property?

Thanks!

Comment: Because stored properties are instance variables which are given compiler-synthesized get and set functions

Comment: Related: [How can you conform protocol variables' set & get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40820913/how-can-you-conform-protocol-variables-set-get) – In particular: *"The protocol doesn’t specify whether the property should be a stored property or a computed property—it only specifies the required property name and type."*

Answer (score 2):

```
protocol UserType {
    var name: String { get }
    var age: Int { get set }
}
```

The important thing to understand is that `{ get }` and `{ get set }` are merely *notations*. They have nothing to do with "getter and setter". They are merely ways of describing to the compiler what the protocol's requirements are. (You could argue that the notation is confusing or misleading, but it's what we've got, so we have to live with it.)

So, basically, all this says is:

- An adopter must declare a `name` String instance property.
- An adopter must also declare an `age` Int instance property and that property must be writable.

That's all it means. Well, you have satisfied those requirements in your adopter (Person). Your code is legal. The end.

Comment: while functionally correct, the get and set annotations have _everything_ to do with a getter and setter, just not a _user defined_ getter and setter.

Comment: @PeejWeej I don't agree. I'm happy you've put your point of view in an answer of your own, but my point, which I stick to, is that, as far as meaning is concerned, the language _could_ have used a totally different notation, e.g. `var name: String; var age: Int { writable }`. Instead, and perhaps a bit confusingly, the language just "reused" the `get` and `set` already used for a computer property getter and setter because that's what it had on hand. To all intents and purposes, this is a _different_ `get` and `set`, and that is what has confused the OP.

Comment: While I agree that the verbiage (though well established in the field) could be better, (personally I think `readable` and `writable` would indeed be better) a `get` and `set` _are required_ from an adhering property. Whether manually overridden in the source code, or generated by the compiler.

Comment: @PeejWeej There is no such thing as a Swift property without a getter, implicitly or explicitly, so the protocol notation could have saved its breath; _any_ `name` String property will be satisfactory. So just `writable` for the `age` property would do, and, as I say, the OP wouldn't have been confused.

Comment: There are swift properties without _visible_ getters, (e.g. any private property), and the current approach allows flexibility to allow setter-only properties in the future without changing the syntax requirements. Regardless, I generally agree with you, but it's untrue that "They have nothing to do with `getter and setter`"

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note first: **Every property has an implicit getter and setter unless otherwise stated**. e.g. a simple `var age: Int` implicitly has a `get` and `set`, and `let age: Int` implicitly has a `get`. When you declare a manual getter and setter, you're *overriding* something, not creating something that didn't otherwise exist.

As for protocols, in explicit terms:

`var name: String { get }` means the adhering Type must have a property with a signature of `name:String` that can be read, AKA. `get`

`var age: Int { get set }` means the adhering Type must have a property with a signature of `age:String` that can be read *or* assigned, AKA `get` and `set`

Note that these rules are **inclusive** not **exclusive**. The requirements don't care how they are satisfied, and don't disallow anything else.

This means with your given example, a property of `let name: String` would work because it only requires access, but `let age: Int` *wouldn't* work, because it cannot be changed. It also doesn't care about internal details, so using computed properties, private setters, etc. is fine as long as they have the necessary access.