# Is let a get only variable?

Tags: swift, protocols, var, let

I'm a little bit confused with this.

We have variables in swift that can have a setter, getter or both and constants which can't change his own initial value,

So, is a var with only a getter the same as a let? If it is, what is the idea in a protocol to set a variable like this

```
protocol myProtocolA {
    var myString: String {get}
}
```

vs

```
protocol myProtocolB {
    let myString: String {get} //I don't think this will compile but I'm curious
}
```

Comment: *"I don't think this will compile"* - try it. What happens?

Comment: let declarations cannot be computed properties

Comment: I tried to explain it best I could, but it seems there are documents that write out how it all works by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)

Comment: This question [Swift Protocol get only settable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573872/swift-protocol-get-only-settable) seems to answer your query