# Why can I set a value for a get-only property of a protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, interface, protocols, swift-protocols

I'm trying to understand how and why to use protocol properties. Here I've tried to create a protocol where I have dummyGet property and dummySet property.
When I conform this protocol in ViewController, I can set both of those properties while dummyGet only has a "getter". What am I missing?

```
protocol TestProtocol {

var dummyGet: String { get }
var dummySet: String { get set }

}

class ViewController: TestProtocol {
    var dummySet: String = ""
    var dummyGet: String = ""
}
```

Comment: Of the answers on the duplicate, I consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38281806/3418066) to be the most helpful; It depends on the effective type that you are accessing.  The get-only restriction only applies when you are accessing the object through the `TestProtocol` interface.  When `ViewController` accesses its own properties it is doing so as an instance of `ViewController`, not through `TestProtocol`.  Try `let x = ViewController() as TestProtocol; x.dummyGet="test"` and see what happens.

Comment: Also note that protocols are *descriptive not restrictive*; They specify the minimum requirements, not constraints.  So `dummySet` must be both gettable and settable (e.g. The requirement can't be satisfied by a constant or computed property) while `dummyGet` must be *at least* gettable and, when accessed via the protocol, cannot be assumed to be settable

Comment: Great answer Paul thank you for that. What does accessing properties via protocol mean?

Comment: I mean when you access a variable of type `TestProtocol`.  For example when I said `let x = ViewController() as TestProtocol` the inferred type of `x` is `TestProtocol`.  Without the `as TestProtocol` the inferred type of `x` is `ViewController`. `dummyGet` of `ViewController` is get/set but `dummyGet` of `TestProtocol` is get only